# How to use information from the URL to click on specific button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a group project for a class, and we have a webpage that is split into different tabs, so it is only one webpage, but appears to be different pages using Jquery so the page doesn't have to reload when switching between tabs.  The problem I am having is that one of the tabs has a form to get information from the user, then after the user clicks the submit button, the info is sent to the database using php, causing the page to reload.  Then depending on if the information was successfully sent to the database, there will be either "success" or "invalid" appended to the end of the URL.  If the user submits this form, we want them to automatically come back to this tab on the reload, and I have tried doing this by using a script like this:

```
<script>
 document.getElementById("baseTab").click();
 window.onload = function() {
 var theurl = document.location.href;
 if (theurl.includes("success") || theurl.includes("invalid") {
  document.getElementById("infoTab").click();
}   
};
</script>
```

The baseTab is the tab we want to load whenever someone first loads the webpage, unless they have just submitted the form on the infoTab page.  This code structure works on a simple test webpage I run on my computer, but when I try to push it to our project repository, it will only do the "baseTab".click, and not click the "infoTab" button even if theurl includes "success" or "invalid".  I tried doing it without the window.onload(), but that doesn't work either.  Also, if I do

```
if (theurl.includes("success") || theurl.includes("invalid") {
 document.getElementById("infoTab").click();
} 
else {
document.getElementById("baseTab").click();
}
```

then neither of the buttons get clicked.  If their is an easier way to do this or you see where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not use Ajax to post the form as well? Then you don't need to reload the page at all when it's submitted.

Comment: It's definitely a possibility,  I just wanted to see if there was anything that would be easier than having to rewrite that code

Comment: How are you appending the status to the URL? As a hash (`#success`), as a part of the url path (`/success`) or as a query string (`?success`)?

Comment: try using `$("yourSelector").tabs({ active: 2 })` to load the specific tab you want after page load

Comment: I'm appending to the url using: header("Location: ../mainpage.php?info=invalid");

Comment: Btw, this row: `if (theurl.includes("success") || theurl.includes("invalid") {` is missing the closing `)` and should throw a JS-error in your console.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! It was throwing an error on line 120 when the file is only 62 lines long so I could not figure out where that error was coming from

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that missing parenthesis was the cause of the script not working, thanks a lot you just saved me a lot of time

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Use your browser console to check errors! First line of troubleshooting when something isn't working as expected